# Spring Cloud Eureka Connecting to a Secured Service

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I'm attempting to establish a discovery server with spring cloud Eureka which needs to connect to a secured client.  I understand how to secure the Eureka sever itself - that isn't the issue.  The issue is in the other direction - how to get Eureka to successfully communicate with a client service that itself is secured.

In other words; I have a discovery client that registers itself with Eureka.  That client implements http basic authentication.  It can and does successfully register itself with the discovery service, however when I attempt to utilize that service with a lookup to the discovery service, I get authentication failures (on the client service itself) which of course makes sense because I haven't specified any credentials anywhere and have no idea how to do so.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from your tags you are using spring-cloud.

When you use your service (with RestTemplate or Feign or manually looking up and interacting with it), your request has nothing to do with Eureka. Eureka only provides you information about your services whereabouts. Once you (or some undelying logic) obtained the address of the service, you are directly communicating with it.